# Where is the global variable in Node.js hiding?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
a = 555
console.log(global.a)
```

outputs **"undefined"**

I have been told that global variables in Node go to the object `global`, but I cannot find it.
What I want to do is to write a function that will "display all global variables I (and only I) have created in my program" so that I can find typos. (Recently I declared global variable `starCounter` instead of assigning to a local parameter `startCounter`)

**UPDATE:**

I just realized my actual test file had two more lines and those lines were causing the problem.

```
a = 555
console.log(global.a)
return; 
var a = Math.pow(4, 3)
```

But now this puzzles me even more?! Why would local variable assignment that is never reached after the **return** statement, would screw up the global variable assignment?

Comment: When I was asking this question I was presented with "captcha" which was definitely someone's house number photo. Am I participating in a surveillance program?

Comment: Tried your code, it worked well in my node REPL.

Comment: node --version: v0.8.14

Comment: Tried in `node v0.8.14` and it's the same. Your code works fine.

Comment: Do you mean there is something wrong with _me_?

Comment: You can declare a global variable using `global.a = 555`

Comment: http://ideone.com/2cnEFe This is created with `node v0.8.11`. It prints `555` as expected.

Comment: Strange, evaluating from command line works fine! c:\euler\node.exe -e "a=555; console.log(global.a)" ---- 555

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. http://ideone.com/2cnEFe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `global` to find typos in your code.

The best way to do so is to enable [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).

There are two ways to do so.

First way is to enable it globally with `--use_strict` v8 option when starting your node app. I'm not sure that it's a good idea if you're using third party modules which you obviously do.

Second way is to add

```
"use strict";
```

at the top of each `.js` file in your project.

## Update

As for your second question, see [MDN docs on var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

Answer (score 1):

I just created this in node v0.8.11. Looks like its working fine. http://ideone.com/2cnEFe

```
a = 555
console.log(global.a)
```

**Edit:** To answer your second question, when you do something like this

```
var a = 555;
```

The variable will be created in the local scope. But when you do

```
a = 555;
```

the variable will be created in global scope. But when you do.

```
a = 555;
var a;
```

The variable will still be created in local scope only. So, in the following code, `a` will not be created as a `global` variable. Thats why you get an `undefined`.

```
a = 555
console.log(global.a)
return; 
var a = Math.pow(4, 3)
```

Read an interesting story about missing `var` in the declaration. [HOW ONE MISSING `VAR` RUINED OUR LAUNCH](http://blog.safeshepherd.com/23/how-one-missing-var-ruined-our-launch/)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> a = 555
> console.log(global.a)
> return; 
> var a = Math.pow(4, 3)
> ```
>
> But now this puzzles me even more?! Why would local variable
>   assignment that is never reached after the return statement, would
>   screw up the global variable assignment?

Because of [*hoisting*](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html). The assignment is never reached and executed, but the variable has been *declared* in your current scope with the [`var` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Just as function declarations, they are available from when you enter the (function) scope. Your code is equivalent to

```
var a;
a = 555
console.log(global.a)
return; 
a = Math.pow(4, 3)
```